# swift optional crash with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

I'm currently getting some crash reports in Flurry at this particular line of code:

```
var hasSeenConnectionPrompt = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("has-seen-connection-prompt") as? Bool ?? false
```

It's impossible for me to reproduce and I assumed when first writing the code, that if 'has-seen-connection-prompt' is nil, the expression will return false.

Could anyone shed some light on why this might be crashing?

Stack trace (xxxxxx is the app name):

```
0   xxxxxxxx                            0x0014e628 showConnectionAlertFirstTimeOnly + 3920 (FullProfileView.swift:100)
1   xxxxxxxx                            0x0014d66c onIntroduce + 2140 (FullProfileView.swift:95)
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2be874a1 <redacted> + 12
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2bde393d __CFXNotificationPost + 1784
4   Foundation                          0x2cb139b9 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
5   Foundation                          0x2cb1851f -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
6   xxxxxxxx                            0x000f16c8 init + 3520 (MainViewController.swift:86)
7   xxxxxxxx                            0x000f0df4 init + 1260 (MainViewController.swift:0)
8   xxxxxxxx                            0x000f0e54 init + 1356 (MainViewController.swift:0)
9   UIKit                               0x2f636e13 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1166
10  UIKit                               0x2f9c12d1 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 48
11  UIKit                               0x2f639017 <redacted> + 150
12  UIKit                               0x2f47d257 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 102
13  UIKit                               0x2f47d0fb -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 294
14  UIKit                               0x2f47cbe9 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 968
15  UIKit                               0x2f3a0845 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
16  UIKit                               0x2f3a0757 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
17  QuartzCore                          0x2ed99599 <redacted> + 236
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39adc8b7 <redacted> + 22
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39ae00bf __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 722
20  CoreFoundation                      0x2be94be9 <redacted> + 8
21  CoreFoundation                      0x2be932e9 <redacted> + 1512
22  CoreFoundation                      0x2bde1621 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
23  CoreFoundation                      0x2bde1433 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
24  GraphicsServices                    0x331900a9 _GSEventRunModal + 136
25  UIKit                               0x2f3cc359 _UIApplicationMain + 1440
26  xxxxxxxx                            0x00125624 init + 2060 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x39afcaaf <redacted> + 2
```

Comment: That code looks perfectly OK and should not crash. Probably the error is somewhere else. Note that you can achieve the same with `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("has-seen-connection-prompt")`.

Comment: Can you please post the full crash report and symbolicated stack trace?

Comment: Added the stack trace